# String with HTML is nulled with json_encode in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have an array, and one of the elements in the array has a string with HTML tags.  When I iterate through the array and echo the field, I can see the string.

```
    $positions = $jobs_dbc->getData($sql);
    foreach($positions as $position) {
        echo $position['PositionDescription'];
    }
```

In the example below, there are a total of 3 elements in the $positions array.  The first two do not have HTML tags in PositionDescription.  The 3rd record does, and I've highlighted the results of the code above:

[image: string with html tags]

BUT - when I json_encode the array, that 3rd record's PositionDescription shows up as NULL.

```
echo json_encode($positions, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_QUOT);
```

The code above returns:
[image: json encoded results]

How do I get the string with HTML encoded?

**UPDATES:**

```
var_export($positions)
array ( 0 => array ( 'PositionName' => 'Front End Sales', 'PositionManagement' => '0', 'PositionDescription' => 'Works in scratch bakery department to provide guest care, package, stock & merchandise fresh bakery products. Responsible for accurate rotation of products & recording sales & loss. Will take in-person & phone orders for special occasion cakes & other bakery products.', 'DepartmentName' => 'Bakery', ), 1 => array ( 'PositionName' => 'Baker', 'PositionManagement' => '0', 'PositionDescription' => 'Works in scratch bakery department to provide guest service & produce donuts, pastries & bread. Will use variety of machines to assist with meeting production goals including deep fryer, sheeter, mixer, scale and oven.', 'DepartmentName' => 'Bakery', ), 2 => array ( 'PositionName' => 'Part-time Accounting Clerk I', 'PositionManagement' => '0', 'PositionDescription' => 'APPLY BY FRIDAY 10/9/09! PART-TIME = 25 hours/wk, flex shifts M-F between 8am-4pm. Position: Accounting Clerk I Department: Accounting Reports To: Accounting Manager Position Summary: The Accounting Clerk I assists other Accounting Clerks with communication between accounts payable and the vendor community ensuring that all related documentation and paperwork is completed in a timely and accurate manner. They also assist in the processing of past due statements creating a trusted relationship between the accounting department and the vendors we partner with. Responsibilities: 1. Provides world-class service and mentors all co-workers towards providing the same passionate service at all times. 2. Researches and reviews vendor statements in order to facilitate the prompt processing of accounts payable activity. 3. Provides recap of vendor coupon totals received from the stores and prepares coupon bundles for mailing to coupon processing center. 4. Works in and cultivates a team oriented work environment by sharing work knowledge and offering assistance to co-workers as needed including vacation coverage. 5. Maintains confidentiality of departmental/company data, initiatives and other sensitive information. 6. Provides support to the stores by answering questions and troubleshooting accounts payable issues as they develop. 7. Adheres to all company policies and procedures creating a professional and enjoyable work environment. Qualifications: •Adept with PC based software applications including MS Office •Demonstrated 10-key by touch and proficient keyboarding skills •Strong organization and problem solving skills •Exhibits passionate commitment to detail and accuracy •Math skills necessary, but not limited to: reading and interpreting reports •Excellent communication skills with the ability to communicate with co-workers and other crew members in English, demonstrate professional phone etiquette, courteously answer telephone calls and promptly respond to voicemail/email messages •Must be at least 18 years of age due to equipment use and work environment Work Environment: Work space will be primarily in office environment in an assigned cubicle. General office schedule is Monday-Friday with flexible work hours between 8am-4pm. Typically a part-time position. Physical activity: Sitting, fingering, standing/walking, bending, twisting, reaching, pushing/pulling Tools and Equipment: Computer, printer, scanner, telephone, 10-key calculator, fax machine, copier. This job description is representative only and is not exhaustive of the tasks that a crew member in the position may be required to perform. Haggen, Inc. reserves the right to request and require its crew members to perform other tasks depending on circumstances or emergencies. ', 'DepartmentName' => 'Corporate', ), )
```

Comment: Please post `var_export($positions)`. Preferably as plain text rather than an image.

Comment: Could you tell us the character encoding of the string? `echo mb_detect_encoding($positions)`

Comment: @Jimmie - I don't get any results when I do that.

Comment: @Barmar - I've updated the original post with the results of var_export

Comment: I don't see any HTML tags in there. I guess the tags are being interpreted when you display the output of `var_export` on your web page.

Comment: @Barmar - I've copied the data from the database to a text editor, and it contains characters like "•".  I thought these were html tags, but they are not. I was able to use utf8_encode to get the field in the correct format, and now json_encode works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the PositionDescription had HTML tags, but once I looked at the data in the database, I saw characters like bullets, which were not HTML tags but the actual symbol.

json_encode required utf8 characters.  Once I converted the field to utf8, json_encode started to return the string.

```
foreach($positions as &$position) {
        $position['PositionDescription'] = utf8_encode($position['PositionDescription']);
    }

echo json_encode($positions, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_QUOT);
```